# SwiftUI Optional @Binding doesn't update its value on the first change

Tags: swift, swiftui

It was two days and I trying to figure out the reason of why the optional binding value doesn't change from the first time if its has value unless I make the change on the second time (I make the change twice to response the binding value), but if the binding value is nil and then I set it it works fine from the first time, its something very odd, If anyone can help me with this?

this is the sample code

```
    struct ParentView: View {
        
        @State var list: ListOfTasks?
        @State private var listGroup: ListOfTasks? = nil   // first value of binding
        
        var body: some View {
            // UI code here
            // Pass the value to "ChildView"
            NavigationLink(
                destination: ChildView(sublistGroup: $listGroup)) {
                // UI code here
            }
            .onAppear {
                // Set the binding value if we have it or its still nil
                if let editList = list {
                    listGroup = editList.origin
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    struct ChildView: View {
        
        @Binding var listGroup: ListOfTasks?
        
        var body: some View {
            // UI code here
            .onTapGesture {
                // Here I try to change the listGroup value by give it some value or set it to nil, 
                // the problem is when I tap once it's not work unless I tap twice to respond the change.
                // listGroup = new value
                // listGroup = nil
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: There's a lot of stuff missing that someone would have to mock out in order to debug this. Can you create a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: is ListOfTask defined as struct or class?

Comment: Are you doing `listGroup = nil` straight after `listGroup = new value`? The Binding won't react in that case, because there value was the same (nil) before and after the onTapGesture.

Comment: The all thing missing is just simple UI stuff," ListOfTask" is class and I didn't doing listGroup = nil straight after listGroup = new value"listGroup = nil" I just explain that sometime I set it to value and sometime I set to nil.

Comment: @State is not meant to be used with class, classes  are reference types.

Comment: As @TusharSharma wrote `@State` won't work with classes like you expect it to do. You could either change it to a struct or add conformance to `ObservableObject` and use `@StateObject` instead of `@State`.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the help, actually it's the @State,  it's the source of the problem.